# fadeOut inside the onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a code which shows question on click and also shows answer for certain period of time. The code works fine when there is no fadeOut function inside the code. As soon as I put the fadeOut function, the question and answer is shown only once. After that only question is shown . Why is this happening ?

Here is my code link :http://jsfiddle.net/sagesony/6qDap/1058/

and the code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">   
</script>
<body>
    <p>Question: <span id="question"></span></p>
    <p>Answer: <span id="answer"></span></p>
    <input id="start" type="button" value="start"/>
    <input id="show" type="button" value="show answer"/>
<script>
    document.getElementById("start").onclick=function(){
       var i=Math.round(Math.random()*3);
       var verbs=["play","run","go","kill"];
       document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=verbs[i];
       document.getElementById("show").onclick=function(){
            var answers=["golf","dog","school","none"];
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=answers[i];
            $("#answer").fadeOut(1000);
       };
   };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

because fadeOut is setting your element to display:none; after fading.
so, you have to set this element visible again to fadeOut again.

just use:

```
.show()
```

to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Valtos/6qDap/1060/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a delay like

```
var verbs = ["play", "run", "go", "kill"];
var answers = ["golf", "dog", "school", "none"];
//register click handler
$('#start').click(function () {
    var i = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
    $("#question").html(verbs[i]);
    $('#show').click(function () {
        $("#answer").html(answers[i]).delay(1000).fadeOut();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show it again: http://jsfiddle.net/6qDap/1063/

```
 $("#answer").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $(this).show().text('');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens since after calling the `fadeOut()` method the `answer` span is hidden forever. You will have to do something to show it again like below:

```
var i = 0;
var verbs = ["play", "run", "go", "kill"];
var answers = ["golf", "dog", "school", "none"];

$('#start').click(function () {
    i = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
    $('#question').html(verbs[i]);
});

$('#show').click(function () {
    $("#answer").html(answers[i]).show().fadeOut(1000);
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cVM9e/)